# Django unknown column error when trying to get a model objects

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm, inspectdb

I'm trying to set up a web-app that modify an existing MySQL database using Dajngo, the model for my table below was generated via Django inspectdb:

```
class BaseCase(models.Model):
    base_case_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    version = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    default = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'base_case'
```

and here is an SQL of that base_case table in the database :

```
CREATE TABLE `base_case` (
  `base_case_name` tinytext,
  `version` tinytext,
  `default` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

the problem is when I try to get the objects via Django ORM I keep getting this error

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'base_case.id' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: can you show the query?

Comment: BaseCase.objects.all()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by **defining a primary key** in the **BaseCase Table**, Django try to match the primary key column to its own generated id (base_case.id) in the field list.

Comment: I looked for so long, so long. I had this happen when I was trying to pull an entire table into my views page without specifying a column name. KUDOS to you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations

$ python manage.py migrate
```

run following command in order for changes to be applied to the database.

Comment: I got these errors when running makemigrations : 

SFP.EAD: (models.E004) 'id' can only be used as a field name if the field also sets 'primary_key=True'.

SFP.GAD.country: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'GAD.country' clashes with reverse accessor for 'GAD.country_code'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'GAD.country' or 'GAD.country_code'.

Comment: I think you have issue regarding some model Fields mismatch.

Comment: for the first error, I have a column named id in EAD table, and Django generate id field by default for each model I don't know how to resolve this because I don't have the right to change anything in the database for the second error I'm still lost :/

Comment: I suggest You Alter Your Table Manual In Database For Remove Id Field.

Comment: even though I altered the table and fixed the previous problems and after running the migration commands successfully, I still get the same error when running BaseCase.objeects.all() :/

Comment: BaseCase Modal has Any Records?@MehdiSelbi

Comment: I think you should remove all records and the re-migrate whole database

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately I don't have the right to do it :/ , is there any other solution

Comment: Sorry but I have no other solution. please upvote if this answer helps you. thank you.

Comment: I upvoted I'm new in StackOverflow it's not registered yet, anyway I found a solution check the below answer ;)

Comment: Okay @MehdiSelbi

Answer (score 0):

```
class Images(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    image = models.FileField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Set primary_key=True  which field you want to set as the primary key.

Comment: If you can, it's better if you create the example using OP's base model in order to prevent confusion. Django models already have an id-field by default that's set as the primary key

Comment: Actually, it depends on which field he wants to set the primary key to. I gave the example of setting the primary key.

Comment: That's correct, if you want to use a different field as the primary key you have to specify that yourself. However by default any django Model created has a primary key set by default, which is accessible via `id` on the model. However if you are trying to fetch a model using `Model.objects.filter` you should use the `pk` value: `Model.objects.filter(pk=id_of_obj)`